# Add Acrobat Reader XI AxtiveX to Gupta (Centura) Team Developer 3.0 project

Tags: acrobat, centura

I have to make some changes to a large reporting application, built with *centrua team developer 3.0* (`tpf3`).

One of the changes is to enable to open reports with a more recent version of acrobat reader. There is a `.apl` file that works with the *activex* that came with *acrobat reader 6.0*, and that is still working.
After adding (creating) a `.apl` file for the *Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0*, I compiled all my sources, but got this error:

> activex creation failed

Is it possible to add the *AcroPDF.dll* into a project that is done with *CTD 3.0*, or do we need to upgrade to *CTD 6.x* ? Did someone already implement *Reader XI* into a *CTD* project ?

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that with TD3.1 PTF4 I get the same problem when creating an apl and then compiling the application.

I tried to do the same with TD6.2 and it worked properly. I was able to open and show a PDF-Document with just one line of code.

What I did: I started TD62 ActiveX-Explorer, created a Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0.apl with option Generate Full by Name, used the control in a form window and called

> Set bRet = axAcrobat.LoadFile( sFilename, bOk )